# Is my 19.04 using nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, 19.04

I have laptop with both intel and nvidia cards.
I've installed latest nvidia driver through software centre and rebooted the system. It seems like everything went well without any visible error.
When I run `prime-select query` it returns `nvidia`. But when I go "Settings -> Details -> about" it still showing "Intel Graphics". Also when I run `glmark2` it shows this:

```
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     Intel Open Source Technology Center
    GL_RENDERER:   Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) 
    GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 19.0.2
```

How do I activate nvidia card?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you logging into a wayland session? If so you'll fall back to the Intel driver. If not does this return a file name or nothing?  `ls /lib/modprobe.d |grep blacklist-nvidia.conf`

Comment: @doug - thanks for the reply! Nope, there is no such file:
> root ~ # ls /lib/modprobe.d 
aliases.conf  blacklist_linux_4.15.0-55-generic.conf  blacklist_linux_5.0.0-23-generic.conf  fbdev-blacklist.conf  nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf  nvidia-kms.conf  systemd.conf
And yes, I am logging into wayland session.
My concern is that nvidia could be activated only while I am playing a game, but I don't know how to check it.

Comment: Your nvidia driver will not be used in a wayland session for anything..

Comment: thanks, doug. You mean for anything-anything? Is it a well known thing? I'd like to know more.

Comment: man, you are certainly was right. I've logged in through X (thankfully ubuntu login screen allows to choose a DE) and now all tests like ` glmark2` are showing that nvidia is being used. Cheers!

Comment: There may be some isolated uses of nvidia (optimus cards) while in a wayland session.. For instance with a properly enabled mpv one could use nvdec-copy for hardware accelerated playback in wayland sessions